# Activate QMainWindow in Astra Linux

Tags: linux, qt, qmainwindow, qevent

I have an application with some windows, and one of them is modal. On Windows OS, I can't raise the not modal window by clicked on it when the modal window is activated. On Linux (I'm using Astra Linux) I can do this (not modal window will raise). I checked all `QEvent` from windows, but there're no events when I clicked on the not modal window. How can I fix this on Astra Linux?

Comment: Well.. No answer.. No solution..

Comment: try playing around with window flags, Astra window manager is buggy in older versions